# Measures with a continuous density function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

For simplicity, let's just consider the measure space $\mathbb R$ with the lebesgue measure $\lambda$. If a measure $\mu <<\lambda$ (abosolutely continuous), then by Radon–Nikodym theorem,  $\mu$ has a density $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, which is locally integrable.

I am wondering if there is a property $\mathcal P$ such that if the measure $\mu$ satisfies $\mathcal P$, then $f=d\mu/d\lambda$ is a continuous function. (Sorry for being too "formal" with the word "property" here.)

I am asking this because I came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075773/topology-and-measures/1075784#1075784) by Ian. In the answer, it is claimed that if a radon measure $\mu<< \lambda$, then $f$ is continuous. So here, the property $\mathcal P$ is "being a radon measure". However, if we consider the measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ with density being the Heaviside function,
$$
H(x)=1,x\ge 0\\
H(x)=0, x<0
$$ 
then $\mu$ is a radon measure, but the density $H$ is not continuous. (The antiderivative of $H$ is indeed continuous: $[xH(x)]'=H(x)$.)

So, I am thinking about a property $\mathcal P$ described in the language of measure theory that could imply the continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

One known sufficient conidition is the following: If $\mu$ is a finite measure whose Fourier transform is integrable then $\mu$ has  continuous density (which is given by the inversion theorem).

Comment: Why $\mu$ must be finite?

Comment: @Jethro The Fourier transform of  finite measure is a function. For an infinite measure it is generalized function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problem is with the cited answer, which I think is a wrong-headed.  The other answer, by Ilya, is more to the point.

In short, the premise of this problem is false: Radon-Nikodym derivatives need not be continuous, and the "property" the OP wants to generalize is false.

Consider the pair of measures $\sigma$ and $\tau$ which are the restrictions of Lebesgue measure  to the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$, respectively, so for each measurable $A$ we have $\sigma(A)=\lambda(A\cap[0,1])$ and $\tau(A)=\lambda(A\cap[0,2])$. They are both Radon measures, and it is easy to check that $\sigma\ll\tau$ and $\tau\ll\lambda$, and that the Radon Nikodym derivative of $\sigma$ with respect to $\tau$ is the function $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$, or at least is $\tau$-a.e. equal to that. No measure $0$ modification of this function is continuous.

The original [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075773/topology-and-measures) brings out the problem caused by the multiple meanings of the word "continuous" in this context.  It is true that if $\tau\ll\lambda$ the function $x\mapsto \tau([a,x])=\int_a^x f\,d\lambda$ is absolutely continuous, but it is not true that $f$ is necessarily continuous.  Add to this the fact that all measures are continuous in the sense that they preserve monotone convergence. The accepted answer to that original question does not help.

Comment: So, is there a notion of "measure with continuous density"?

Comment: Of course there is, but it's not as simple as merely being an RN derivative.

Comment: Could you give me an example of such a notion/property? I am actually more interested in knowing how to express the "continuity" I described.

Comment: Any characterization of continuous functions will serve for such a $\mathcal P$. How useful, however, is another question.

Comment: Yes. I am also starting to feel that such a notion is unlikely to be very useful.